# Django + Docker + Postgres. FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"

Tags: django, postgresql, docker

I don't know how to solve this simple error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError:  FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

When I run `docker-compose up`, it can't connect to Postgres. I have tried stopping the service with `docker-compose down -v`. Please help me understand why am I getting this error.

Django settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:15
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
```

I've reviewed many tutorials and videos about this without success.

Comment: Try to follow this https://github.com/mohanlalprajapati/groceryshop. It may help you.

Comment: @MohanlalPrajapati your database configurations in settings.py are hidden...

Answer (score 1):

Try to expose the port of postgres in db service in your docker-compose